# Assign default value to column in SharePoint library using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-library

I am writing a script for assigning the default value of a column in SharePoint library:

```
$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text
$sList.Fields.Add("OpCoNam",$spFieldType,$true)
$sList.Fields["OpCoNa"].DefaultValue="$sList.Title"
$sList.Update()
```

But no value is getting added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the field as below

```
$spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text
$sList.Fields.Add("OpCoNam",$spFieldType,$true)
$sList.Update()

$f = $sList.Fields["OpCoNam"]
$f.DefaultValue = "DefaultValue"
$f.Update()
```

Comment: Amal: thanks it is working but the column created is a mandatory value column. Any way to make it non-mandatory?

Comment: Yes, pass $false to `Add` method